# How to pass multiple values via operator chain to map operator? In NgRx Effect

Tags: javascript, rxjs, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am working on `Effect`, in which I load new data form `REST` endpoint and then dispatch action to update store with received data. Together with composing `searchUrl`, there is some computation of `newCurrentPage`.

How to pass `newCurrentPage` value along with search request to following operatos?

Code looks like this:

```
@Effect()
tablePageChanged = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(action.tablePageChanged ),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select('tableData')),
        switchMap(([action, tableData]) => {

            let newCurrentPage: number;
            let searchUrl: string;

            switch (action.navPage) {

                case NavigationPage.First:
                    newCurrentPage = 1;
                    searchUrl = tableData.devsTable.firstUrl;
                    break;

                case NavigationPage.Previous:
                    newCurrentPage = tableData.devsTable.currentPage - 1;
                    searchUrl = tableData.devsTable.previousUrl;
                    break;

                case NavigationPage.Next:
                    newCurrentPage = tableData.devsTable.currentPage + 1;
                    searchUrl = tableData.devsTable.nextUrl;
                    break;

                case NavigationPage.Last:
                    newCurrentPage = Math.ceil(tableData.devsTable.totalRecords / tableData.devsTable.pageSize);
                    searchUrl = tableData.devsTable.lastUrl;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            // HERE: I want to return also 'newCurrentPage', so that I can pass it to 'handleSuccessfulResponse' later
            return this.http.get<UserSearchResponse>(searchUrl, {observe: 'response'});
        }),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select('tableData')),
        map(([response, tableData]) => {

            // HERE: I want to get 'newCurrentPage' to pass it to the 'handleSuccessfulResponse' function
            return this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response, tableData);
        })
    );
```

This `RxJS` thing is quite new for me, and I haven't quite wrapped my head around it yet, so please be explicit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move operators to the closure where this variables were defined, like this:

```
switchMap(([action, tableData]) => {
  // ...
  return this.http.get<UserSearchResponse>(searchUrl, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
    // `tableData` and `newCurrentPage` is available here
    map(response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response, tableData))
  );
})
```

Or use `map` operator to return pair of `[response, newCurrentPage]` so it can be used later